# Why can't we see particle tracks in clouds or dense fog?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, atmospheric-science, particle-detectors, cosmic-rays

We can see the tracks of charged particles in a cloud chamber.
According to Wikipedia "A cloud chamber consists of a sealed environment containing a supersaturated vapor of water or alcohol". Also, in nature, supersaturation of water vapour can occur in clouds and fog(maybe).

So my question is can these act as a natural particle detector. And if yes, then why can't we see beautiful tracks of charged particles everywhere around us during winters?

Comment: Build one yourself: https://www.sciencefriday.com/educational-resources/build-a-cloud-chamber/. Look at the difference in the experimental setup versus uncontrolled natural conditions

Comment: Maybe sometimes tracks from atmospheric muons are formed naturally in fog. But how would one see them without a black background and lighting only from the side?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How come I never see cosmic rays in steam like they appear in a cloud chamber?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/368180/)

Comment: The two don't seem to be exactly same because in the other case the solution said, water does not become supersaturated but in case of clouds, it is known that water is in supersaturated form